# Elasticsearch query that returns a result if all values ​are equal to a given parameter

Tags: elasticsearch

I need query which gives the following result: With multi values I want to give a result only if all values ​​is equal to given parameter. For example I have an array of ticket type. Then my query should only return a result if all ticket types is equal to, for example, 10. In this case if I have the next two objects then I only want to get objectTwo with parameter 10:

```
objectOne: [{ticketType:10}, {ticketType:20}]
objectTwo: [{ticketType:10}, {ticketType:10}]
```

I actually need some kind of != operator

Comment: I did not quite understand your question here. Maybe you can change the language a bit, and/or add sample data(only relevant fields) and expected returned data based on your query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this with the combination of must and mus_not. Only must is not enough.

```
POST myIndex/_search
{
  "query": {
        "bool" : {
          "must" : {
            "term" : {
              "ticketType" : {
               "value": "10" // selected ticket type
               }
            }
          },
         "must_not" : {
            "terms" : {
              "ticketType" : [{
               "20","30"  // all other unselected ticket types
              }]
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Boolean query with MUST_NOT is what you're looking for, ie :

```
POST yourindex/_search
{
  "query": {
        "bool" : {
          "must_not" : {
            "term" : {
              "ticketType" : 10
            }
          }
        }
  }
}
```